# PPTP VPN Server Unable to load pages

Tags: server, vpn, pptp

So, I can connect to my VPN fine, but I am unable to access any webpages and 'ping (website)' doesn't work either. If you need any files, ask. Any ideas? I realise that there is not a lot of info here but I don't know what else to put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing localip from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.50 (my servers ip) in /etc/pptpd.conf